# Mojolicious sharing of form element name between Perl and the template

Tags: perl, templates, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I'm new at using Mojolicious and therefore I apologize if this is a basic question but I looked around and couldn't find a good way to do it.

I would like to know what's the best strategy to share the name of form parameters between the Perl code (to be used in param('**element**') and a template (to be used in say INPUT name="**element**" ...>.
Is there a way to define '**element**' somewhere so that it can be used in both the Perl side and the template side? A super global variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correct then `stash` - is answer for your question.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Controller#stash

Example. In controller you have such code:

```perl
sub action {
 my $c = shift;
 $c->stash(name_of_param => $c->param('name_of_param'), another_param => $c->param('another_param'));
 $c->render;
}
```

In template:

```html
<h1><%= $name_of_param %></h1>
<h2><%= $another_param %></h2>
```

I think that more good way not exist.

Comment: Thanks Logioniz, that's what I ended up doing but I was hoping that there would be a better way.